# QGIS expression for setting label visibility by scale

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 3.x and struggling with the labels and I would like to have some expression for setting the visibility of some layers based by scale.

[image]

How can I make some of them disappear?

I tried:

```
   if(@map_scale<2000) then ("fid" = 18) = NULL
```

where "fid" is my data attribute table column
NULL - label invisible when scaling smaller than 2000.

It doesn't work

---

According to the answer below, I used the following expression:

```
  @map_scale<2000 AND FID = 12
```

and I see, that the label I wanted to disappear is displayed, whereas all others I want to keep are gone.

[image]

How can I turn it around?

Comment: You can set scale-depended label visibility in the label properties.

Comment: First if you look at the description.(click on the second line of the context window visible in your picture) you will see that the expected result for this data defined override is 1 or 0 so trying an expression that output a null value wont work. Second if you look at the "if"  syntax (should appear at the right of the expression string builder, you may need to click the "show help" button) you will learn the proper syntax for your if expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to combine the conditions (scale and FID in your example) and return a boolean. If `true`, the label is shown, if `false` it is not displayed.

```
@map_scale<2000 AND FID = 30
```

Which is the same as

```
if(@map_scale<2000 AND FID = 30, true,false)
```

The `CASE` statement might be more suitable than the `IF` if you have several distinct conditions.

That being said, this expression would be better located in the `scale dependent visibility` just above the `show label` section

Comment: It doesn't really work.
When I enter the first formula, the only one label is visible - the label with the FID defined in the formula. The remain several labels under the same conditions are not visible.
Applying your second formula there are no labels visible.

Comment: that's pretty much how you have defined the problem: display for a given fid for a specific scale. For the other features, you would have to define other conditions. That's when the `case` statement becomes useful: a condition for scale 1 and whatever other conditions, like the FID you have provided, another condition for scale 2, another condition for other FID, and a default condition

Comment: Ok so how to make only this layer invisible, whereas the other are visible?

Comment: Layer? Forget about the expression and use the `scale dependent visibility` just above the `show` label section

Comment: I know it, but the result is the same. Sorry I meant label.

Comment: so to hide a specific label (scale + fid), swap the true/false: `if(@map_scale<2000 AND FID = 30, false,true)`

Comment: Yes, now it has started to work. How about more than one? Can I put simply: if(@map_scale<2000 AND FID = 30 AND FID = 12 AND FID 13, false,true) and so on?

Comment: I tried also sth like this:
CASE WHEN
@map_scale>2000 Then Fid = 11, True,False
@map_scale>2000 Then Fid = 13, True,False
End

but expression is invalid

Comment: using OR would be required (a feature cannot have two fid..) `if(@map_scale<2000 AND (FID=12 OR FID= 13),false, true)`. Read the help for the `case` syntax

Comment: OK, it doesn't work, as there is no reaction, but I don't want to bore you now. I will read the case sentence. By now I will create a new data attribute feature and use the expression for one sentence :) Thanks for your help today.